# How to get items that match certain ID from a javascript object

Tags: javascript

I am trying to get comments for a particular page.

So I want to get all comments where the slangID = 0Uwx4oXQVEckArRSZNerwhfDZFF3 into an array or object.
Here is my javascript object:

```
{
"3d0366ccf32c4459b9a38aee0dde425a": {
"comment": "This is up\nI know",
"commentID": "3d0366ccf32c4459b9a38aee0dde425a",
"slangID": "34a97a464b51d81a592cf37c8d83cc9e",
"time_date": "2016-09-15T06:15:09.969Z",
"user_id": "0Uwx4oXQVEckArRSZNerwhfDZFF3",
"username": "james"
},
"4b0839bba81943e9cb511365d2978ad6": {
"comment": "aaaaaaa",
"commentID": "4b0839bba81943e9cb511365d2978ad6",
"slangID": "34a97a464b51d81a592cf37c8d83cc9e",
"time_date": "2016-09-15T06:54:36.026Z",
"user_id": "bHDKSU6aorX9efzBCHy",
"username": "ericel123"
},
"5064603984a3a217ae02cd0dab7ede81": {
"comment": "this\n",
"commentID": "5064603984a3a217ae02cd0dab7ede81",
"slangID": "34a97a464b51d81a592cf37c8d83cc9e",
"time_date": "2016-09-15T06:37:15.113Z",
"user_id": "0Uwx4oXQVEckArRSZNer",
"username": "james"
},
"59691edb302c4d0a70d6bb860e64d4e1": {
"comment": "hello\n",
"commentID": "59691edb302c4d0a70d6bb860e64d4e1",
"slangID": "34a97a464b51d81a592cf37c8d83cc9e",
"time_date": "2016-09-15T06:36:41.308Z",
"user_id": "0Uwx4oXQVEckArRSZNer",
"username": "james"
}
}
```

So I can put the comments in an object called 'comments'.
I tried filter like this:

```
var filtered =  vm.comments.filter(function(item) {
        return item.slangID === sid;
  });
 var comments = filtered;
```

it didn't work out.

Comment: Have you checked [Array.prototype.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)?

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: So loop over, check the id, if matches, push item to an array.... (And do not put swear words in your samples....)

Comment: Your filter looks at least 90% of the way there. I think you just need to debug it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's assume your object is called *commentList*. Just loop all the keys in the object and check if the slang matches, then push to an array.

```
var result = [];
for(var key in commentList){
    if(commentList[key].slangID == theSlangImLookingFor)
        result.push(commentList[key]);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var obj ={
"3d0366ccf32c4459b9a38aee0dde425a": {
"comment": "This is fucked up\nI know",
"commentID": "3d0366ccf32c4459b9a38aee0dde425a",
"slangID": "34a97a464b51d81a592cf37c8d83cc9e",
"time_date": "2016-09-15T06:15:09.969Z",
"user_id": "0Uwx4oXQVEckArRSZNerwhfDZFF3",
"username": "james"
},
"4b0839bba81943e9cb511365d2978ad6": {
"comment": "aaaaaaa",
"commentID": "4b0839bba81943e9cb511365d2978ad6",
"slangID": "34a97a464b51d81a592cf37c8d83cc9e",
"time_date": "2016-09-15T06:54:36.026Z",
"user_id": "bHDKSU6aorX9efzBCHy",
"username": "ericel123"
},
"5064603984a3a217ae02cd0dab7ede81": {
"comment": "fuck this\n",
"commentID": "5064603984a3a217ae02cd0dab7ede81",
"slangID": "34a97a464b51d81a592cf37c8d83cc9e",
"time_date": "2016-09-15T06:37:15.113Z",
"user_id": "0Uwx4oXQVEckArRSZNer",
"username": "james"
},
"59691edb302c4d0a70d6bb860e64d4e1": {
"comment": "hello\n",
"commentID": "59691edb302c4d0a70d6bb860e64d4e1",
"slangID": "34a97a464b51d81a592cf37c8d83cc9e",
"time_date": "2016-09-15T06:36:41.308Z",
"user_id": "0Uwx4oXQVEckArRSZNer",
"username": "james"
}
}
Object.keys(obj).filter(function(k){
  return obj[k].slangID === "34a97a464b51d81a592cf37c8d83cc9e"
});
```

I have used "34a97a464b51d81a592cf37c8d83cc9e" since is the data you provided, change it for "0Uwx4oXQVEckArRSZNerwhfDZFF3" in your coude

Comment: Note that this will return the IDs of the matching comments rather than the comments themselves. You'd then need to look up the comment objects by the IDs.